# How to fix NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String selectQueryForPatient = "SELECT registration_id, dob FROM patient_registration WHERE registration_id IN(SELECT max(registration_id)FROM patient_registration)";

String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO patient_master_info(patient_id) VALUES (?);";
String id = null;
String dob = null;
int generatedID = 0;
try {
  pst = con.prepareStatement(selectQueryForPatient);
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
    id = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1));
    dob = rs.getString(2);
    System.out.println("Id : "+id+" "+"DOB: "+dob);
    Date dt = sdf.parse(dob);
    dob = sdf.format(dt);
    String result = id.concat(dob);
    generatedID = Integer.parseInt(result);
  }

  pst = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
  pst.setInt(1, generatedID);
  pst.execute();
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For input string: `"12919851203"` I got `java.lang.NumberFormatExceptionexception`. How do I fix it?

[image: error trace]`

Comment: Is `dob` a String or a Date? Why not use `getDate`?

Comment: It must be the wrong code you have posted, you’re not formatting any number here. Post code, errors etc as text not images and make sure you tell us what line in the code the stacktrace refers to. Oh, wait. I just saw the parseInt call

Comment: dob is String..!

Comment: Furthermore, you shouldn't use `Date` anymore, it's obsolete. Use one of the classes from the `java.time` package, for example `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer **is not** about the number format exception but about the date format mistake you have made.

For the moment, you are parsing `1986-03-01` into the date `1985-12-03` because your `String dob` contains `-`. You need two distinct formaters to get your result:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

String dob = "1985-03-01";
Date dt = sdfIn.parse(dob);
dob = sdfOut.format(dt);

System.out.println(dob);
```

> 19850301

Of course, one could argue about the need to parse into a `Date` just to get a "similar" `String`, if you are sure about your data being a date, you can just remove `-` using :

```
dob = dob.replaceAll("-", "");
```

Last thing, you should use `java.time` API.

```
String dob = "1985-03-01";

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dob, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
dob = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(dob);
```

Comment: @pioneerGeek86 Note that this is not the final answer because once you will try to `Integer.parse(id.concat(dob))`, you will still get the same problem. Since [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54340417/4391450) already gave the solution, I didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but your problem is that the result of appending a date to an integer value easily exceeds the integer range.

For example, let `id` be "30" and `dob` (as read from the database) be "20190123". The result of `id.concat(dob)` is "3020190123", which is larger than "2147483647", the maximum value for an `int`.

Your sample value `12919851203` is even much larger (almost 13 billion, while Integer.MAX_VALUE is about 2 billion).

---

If the value has to be sortable like numbers (where 2 < 10) then you could change the datatype to `long` or `BigInteger`.

If the sorting doesn't matter (i.e. it's OK that "2" is larger than "10") then you could even store `result` as `String` (into a `VARCHAR` column).

Or you could explain what problem you want to solve so that we could find a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes... I want to ask the same Question.. Actually My motto is to generate separate id in combination with value of (registration id + date of birth).
and that's why I use concat method to add string value and convert it into Integer and push it in to DB.

Comment: Or use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Or keep a `String` if those are just ID.